# Track all outgoing URL requests from browser using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to block the UI when user clicks on any hyperlinks that points to different page on my website.
I know there is a way to track all jquery ajax requests using ajaxStart and ajaxStop and i can use these methods to block my UI when browser is waiting for response from the server.
But is there any way to intercept all outgoing page requests from all major browsers (firefox, Chrome and IE) ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to vote you down just for the fact you want to do this...

Comment: As per Rob W, I agree; I think blocking the UI before close is anti-social, unless it is to prevent data loss. If it's just to hassle the user, it is equally as time-wasting as pop-ups and pop-unders. Might be better to have a 'call to action' block on all pages to encourage users to call/get in touch/get something free?

Comment: (If you outline why you want to do this, it may help readers here. As I imply in my above comment, web-based editors will use this approach to prevent the user losing data, which is obviously a good thing. Redmine and Wordpress both do it).

Comment: Guys - It is the nature of the application, the server is just too busy preparing the page and rendering it that it takes almost 10 seconds before the new page is loaded. And meanwhile there are a lot of other functionalities on the page that user can use and jam up the server and hence this requirement... Thanks for your suggestions anyways. Where is Rob W's answer ? I just marked it as an answer and noticed that he already deleted it

Comment: @Endophage https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340910/is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question-because-of-the-askers-intent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind a delegate event handler that intercepts clicks on all `<a href>` elements that will navigate to a page of your website: http://jsfiddle.net/sNDf3/2/.

```
​$("body").on("click", "a[href]", function(e) {
    // <a> elements have a .host property which represents the host of the href
    // so you can block internal links only
    if(this.host === "jsfiddle.net" && !confirm("Sure?")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This will work even when you add links later on due to the delegation (binding the actual handler to a persistent parent).

Comment: Why binding click event of body, why not just the anchors ?

Comment: @Jashwant: Because [insert last paragraph of answer].

Comment: Looking at your SO points, I guessed that last paragraph is answer to my question. But I didnt get the last paragraph. So dumb of me, but can you please explain in simple words , please.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that 'on' event is just like earlier 'live' event.

Going through the jQuery documentation and some testing,

I found that 
`$("a[href]").on("click",function(e) {
  // This is not going to work for anchors added later
})`

Comment: @Jashwant: Yes you're correct. Binding it to the `body` with an additional selector works like `.live` did previously.