# How can I monitor outgoing requests from my browser in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, http

I'm trying to log all the requests that sites in my browser make behind the scenes. I can do it manually using Chrome's anylitics or Firebug, but I want to have either (a) a quick js extension that I can bookmark and run on sites when I want to log requests, or (b) a chrome/firefox extension to do so. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827896/track-all-outgoing-url-requests-from-browser-using-jquery) thread asking roughly the same thing, but I want to catch AJAX requests too. How can I go about this?

Comment: I don't get it. What's better than Chrome's dev tools for this?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that if you are still trying to monitor all outgoing requests in a browser now, you may want to also be aware of out-of-band requests, that could be generated for reports like Network Error Logging (NEL) reports. These should be visiable in Fiddler, but wont show in Dev tools, and could be sent after the page that generated them has closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fiddlr

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

This application runs outside of your browser to inspect all data transmitted between your computer and the internet. It's what I use to debug application design and I think it would be great for what you need.

To note once running it will automatically "log" all requests, and they can be easily saved for reviewing later. There are also loads of extensions to the application that may do the same for you.

### Key Features

**HTTP/HTTPS Traffic Recording**
Fiddler is a free web debugging proxy which logs all HTTP(s) traffic between your computer and the Internet. Use it to debug traffic from virtually any application that supports a proxy like IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera and more.

**Tamper-client-requests-and-server-responses
Web Session Manipulation**
Easily manipulate and edit web sessions. All you need to do is set a breakpoint to pause the processing of the session and permit alteration of the request/response. You can also compose your own HTTP requests to run through Fiddler.

**Inspect-and-debug-traffic-from-any-client
Web Debugging**
Debug traffic from PC, Mac or Linux systems and mobile devices. Ensure the proper cookies, headers and cache directives are transferred between the client and server. Supports any framework, including .NET, Java, Ruby, etc.

**Decrypt-HTTPS-web-sessions**
Security Testing
Use Fiddler for security testing your web applications -- decrypt HTTPS traffic, and display and modify requests using a man-in-the-middle decryption technique. Configure Fiddler to decrypt all traffic, or only specific sessions.

**Test-the-performance-of-your-web-sites-and-apps**
Performance Testing
Fiddler lets you see the “total page weight,” HTTP caching and compression at a glance. Isolate performance bottlenecks with rules like “Flag any uncompressed responses larger than 25kb.”

---

**Update:**

Google Chrome Developer tools (Specifically the Network Tab) You are able to easily see network traffic directly from the current webpage and monitor all HTTP information such as request and response headers, cookies and timing elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jQuery [Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

> These methods register handlers to be called when certain events, such as initialization or completion, take place for any Ajax request on the page. The global events are fired on each Ajax request if the global property in jQuery.ajaxSetup() is true, which it is by default. Note: Global events are never fired for cross-domain script or JSONP requests, regardless of the value of global.